# AWS RDS Concurrency Question (multi-user)

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-concurrency

I am trying to build a desktop application and ideally connect to AWS RDS (MySQL) database. My use case is that at least 5 users will be using this app at the same time and be writing into the database at the same time likely. My question is does RDS handle concurrency issue? Or do I need to write some script to handle this in the desktop app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDS is a managed service, you don't need to worry about concurrency or other configurations, unless and until you need any custom behavior.
The maximum number of simultaneous database connections varies by the DB engine type and the memory allocation for the DB instance class. The maximum number of connections is set in the parameter group associated with the DB instance, except for Microsoft SQL Server, where it is set in the server properties for the DB instance in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

You can read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections) more.